# Add Column Name Convention to EF6 FluentAPI

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-fluent-api

This question was asked here 4 years ago: [EF Mapping to prefix all column names within a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429961/ef-mapping-to-prefix-all-column-names-within-a-table)  I'm hoping there's better handling these days.

I'm using EF6 Fluent API, what I'll call Code First Without Migrations.  I have POCOs for my models, and the majority of my database column names are defined as `[SingularTableName]Field` (e.g., CustomerAddress db column maps to Address field in Customers POCO)

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customers (
    -- ID, timestamps, etc.
    CustomerName NVARCHAR(50),
    CustomerAddress NVARCHAR(50)
    -- etc.
);
```

**Model:**

```
public class Customer
{
    // id, timestamp, etc
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}    
}
```

**ModelBuilder:**

```
modelBuilder<Customer>()
    .Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("CustomerName");
modelBuilder<Customer>()
    .Property(x => x.Address).HasColumnName("CustomerAddress");
```

**Goal:**

What I'd really like is to be able to say something like this for the FluentAPI:

```
modelBuilder<Customer>().ColumnPrefix("Customer");
// handle only unconventional field names here
// instead of having to map out column names for every column
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [model-based code-first conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469439(v=vs.113).aspx) this has become very simple. Just create a class that implements `IStoreModelConvention` ...

```
class PrefixConvention : IStoreModelConvention<EdmProperty>
{
    public void Apply(EdmProperty property, DbModel model)
    {
        property.Name = property.DeclaringType.Name + property.Name;
    }
}
```

... and add it to the conventions in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(new PrefixConvention());
```

Comment: Thanks. I skimmed it quickly but will have to dig in a bit later.  Question: I'm not using an EDMX model, just POCOs and the fluent API config with db initialize off.   Is this still applicable without the EDMX models (I ask because I see the EdmProperty, which I'm unfamiliar with offhand).

Comment: What's more, it can *only* be used with code-first :) But in the background, EF always builds an EDM (Entity data Model), hence the name EdmProperty.

Comment: Excellent.  This looks great - I didn't actually expect an answer to this, so I'm very glad to see it!

Comment: I've got a bunch of `Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name ... is already defined.` when running `add-migration` after adding this

Comment: @Toolkit Please ask a new question so you give all required details.