# Set dynamic column name for same parameter of entity for different tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class Auditable which has four fields CreatedBy, CreatedDate... I have overridden the SaveChanges method to automatically populate the above data whenever an Entity is saved to the database since all tables have the same Auditable column names.

```
public abstract class Auditable
{
    public decimal? CREATEDBY { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CREATEDDATE { get; set; }
    public decimal? MODIFIEDBY { get; set; }
    public DateTime? MODIFIEDDATE { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    decimal? loggedinUserId = null;
    if (_httpContext.Items["USER"] != null)
    {
        var userInfo = _httpContext.Items["USER"];

        Type userBasicType = userInfo.GetType();

        IList<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(userBasicType.GetProperties());

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            if (prop.Name == "Id")
            {
                loggedinUserId = (decimal)prop.GetValue(userInfo, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Auditable>())
    {
        var entity = entry.Entity;

        if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            entity.CREATEDBY = loggedinUserId;
            entity.CREATEDDATE = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {    
            entity.MODIFIEDBY = loggedinUserId;
            entity.MODIFIEDDATE = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

The above code works perfectly and audit columns are populated when the column names are same for multiple tables

Now, my client wants the column names to be changed and have a prefix for every column. So, now my columns looks like TN1_CreatedBy, TN1_CreatedDate, TN2_CreatedBy, TN2_CreatedDate etc...

Is there a way to modify my class Auditable, so that it works automatically for each table with the new predefined prefix? I know what prefix will be coming for each table.

Comment: Hi, this is simmilar to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674883/add-column-name-convention-to-ef6-fluentapi/40677226

Comment: No, the question is there are multiple tables with different column names that needs to be mapped to my same Auditable class